# lvl system not working with mysql - Discord Bot

Tags: mysql, discord.js

So Im trying to make leveling system in my bot but the problem is that when it reaches enough xp to lvl up it will remove the xp but wont add level. I dont know what is wrong with my code but its not working Im using the same technique for editing xp so it adds them but its not working for lvl so Imagine it like this. `User message ---> generates enough xp for lvl up ---> lvls up`. But instead of that it remains on level 1 I think I was searching everywhere for answer but found none. My code is here:

```
  let prf = ".";
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  if(message.author.bot) return;

  con.query(`SELECT * FROM xplvl WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql;
    if (rows.length < 1){
      sql = `INSERT INTO xplvl (id, xp, lvl) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', ${Generatexp()}, ${lvlup()})`
    }else{
      let xp = rows[0].xp;
      let lvl = rows[0].lvl;
      let tnlx = 100 * lvl;
      let l = 1;
      sql = `UPDATE xplvl SET xp = ${xp + Generatexp()} WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;
      if(xp >= tnlx) {
        sql = `UPDATE xplvl SET lvl = ${lvl + l} WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;
        sql = `UPDATE xplvl SET xp = 0`;
        message.channel.send("You leveled up!")
        con.query(sql);
        return;
      }
    }
    con.query(sql)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because every time you go in to update the level, you are explicitly resetting the experience points back to zero which brings back to level 1 on any subsequent attempts.  Then it updates ALL RECORDS back to an xp = 0.

**REMOVE your update query resetting the XP = 0.**

You are building the sql command to update the level, but never executing it.  Then immediately change the sql command to just the xp = 0 (which will do for EVERY record) and thus the level never gets updated.

I also don't think you really mean to reset the xp level and here's why.  Your level's appear to be multiple of 100... thus

```
Level   Points
1       100
2       200
3       300
```

By resetting the xp, getting to level 1 is no problem.  Person earned 100 points.  Now they are forced back to 0.  Now the person has to get 100 points again and it says... ok, you hit level 1 again, back to level 1 and reset to zero.  It will never get to 200.